# AJAX response is the original HTML

Tags: c#, jquery, html, ajax

I'm using AJAX to populate some cascading combo box as shown in the next image:

[image]

When an option is selected in the combo box, it should populate the "Municipio" combo box, to do such a thing I invoke a method using AJAX called CargarCombos(int intAccion, string strCodigo), this method receives the next information:

[image]

But the problem resides when receiving the response from the AJAX method, it seems it's not invoking the method mentioned before and to top it all it just responds the same HTML source code that the page contains, has seen here:

[image]

If you guys can help me I would be totally grateful. Thanks.

EDIT:

Following the suggestions I'm adding the AJAX command and the WEBMethod:

AJAX:

```
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: pageUrl + '/CargarCombos',
            data: '{intAccion: ' + $Accion + ', strCodigo: ' + JSON.stringify($ComboBox.val()) + ' }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
                PopularControl(response.d, $control);
            },
            failure: function(response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
```

WEBMEthod:

```
[WebMethod()]
public static ArrayList CargarCombos(int intAccion, string strCodigo)
{
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

    ////LLamo a las variables necesarias.
    BLL.cDirecciones DireccionesDAL = new BLL.cDirecciones();
    Util.cFuncion oUtil = new Util.cFuncion();

    DataSet oDataCombos = new DataSet();

    oDataCombos = DireccionesDAL.CargarCombos(intAccion, strCodigo);
    if (oDataCombos.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in oDataCombos.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            list.Add(new ListItem(row.ItemArray[1].ToString(), row.ItemArray[0].ToString()));
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Any chance you can post actual relevant code and any errors?

Comment: Sorry but it's not showing any type of error on the firebug in any of the different tabs, sorry for not giving you more information, but that's the same reason I haven't been able to solve it.

Comment: Are you calling the WebMethod via JQuery?

Comment: Actually by AJAX but yes, that's right.

Comment: Could you add the basics of your WebMethod and maybe the calling javascript code? It bear some clues.

Comment: Given only the information you've provided, it's difficult to say if the WebMethod is even being hit. It appears as though the server is seeing it as a page postback. Try eliminating the client and server-side. Can you call the WebMethod using Fiddler (or other tool) to eliminate client-side? Does a breakpoint in the WebMethod get hit?

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshots, it seems you're using WebForms. If that's the case, is the method you are posting to instance or static? Because if it's not static, or the method isn't marked with the `WebMethod` attribute, this will happen. That's because your `ajax` request is just treated as a normal full postback.

e.g it should look like

```
[WebMethod]
//assuming MyModel is the name of your model class to send back to the client.
public static MyModel CargarCombos(int intAccion, string strCodigo)
{
    //whatever it is you do here
}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the fast response, yeah it's static and it's got the [WebMethod] tag, the ajax method was working before but now it won't do nothing. thanks.

Comment: Ok. So presumably something has changed. Can you update the question to show the code-behind method and the client-side call, I'm sure that we can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling the WebMethod via JQuery, make sure that you're setting the content type to JSON e.g.

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "Pendientes.aspx/CargarCombos",
      data: "{intAccion:1, strCodigo:'BAR'}",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
      }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, this is almost like my method is made, the only difference is that I had to use the JSON.stringify function for the string value passed by the combo box, thanks